# How can I combine two Arrays with the arguments Arrays into one Array in Kotlin?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I want to make one array from two arrays.

```
var a1 = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
var a2 = arrayOf(4, arrayOf(5,6), 7)

var a3 = a1 + a2
```

But I get a compile error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public operator fun <T> Array<???>.plus(element: ???): Array<???> defined 
in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Array<???>.plus(elements: Array<out ???>): 
Array<???> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Array<Int>.plus(elements: Collection<Int>): 
Array<Int> defined in kotlin.collections
```

How can I combine them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type inference kind of works against you in this case. `a1` and `a2` are inferred to be arrays of different types, so you can't add them together. The first thing you should do is to make them the same type `Array<Any>`:

```
var a1: Array<Any> = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
var a2: Array<Any> = arrayOf(4, arrayOf(5,6), 7)
```

Then, you will see an ambiguous method call error about 2 overloads of `plus`. The overloads differ only by the name of the parameter. We want to use the one with the `elements` parameter, which adds all the elements from another array:

```
var a3 = a1.plus(elements = a2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This example should actually work for you.

**Example 1:**

```
import java.util.Arrays

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val array1 = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    val array2 = intArrayOf(4, 5, 6)

    val length = array1.size + array2.size

    val result = IntArray(length)
    var pos = 0
    for (element in array1) {
        result[pos] = element
        pos++
    }

    for (element in array2) {
        result[pos] = element
        pos++
    }

    println(Arrays.toString(result))
}
```

**Example 2:**

`arrayCopy` method

```
import java.util.Arrays

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val array1 = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    val array2 = intArrayOf(4, 5, 6)

    val aLen = array1.size
    val bLen = array2.size
    val result = IntArray(aLen + bLen)

    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, result, 0, aLen)
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, result, aLen, bLen)

    println(Arrays.toString(result))
}
```